# Some properties are " read only " in API ressources even if they are allowed to be written in Symfony

Tags: api, symfony, doctrine, entity

i just created a entity "candidate" with symfony and doctrine that you may see below :

```
<

?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use App\Repository\CandidateRepository;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface;

/**
 * @ApiResource(
 *      normalizationContext={"groups"={"user:read"}},
 *      denormalizationContext={"groups"={"user:write"}}
 * )
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=CandidateRepository::class)
 */
class Candidate implements UserInterface, PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @Groups("user:read")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=180, unique=true)
     * @Groups({"user:read", "user:write"})
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="json")
     * @Groups("user:read")
     */
    private $roles = [];

    /**
     * @var string The hashed password
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     * @Groups({"user:read", "user:write"})
     */
    private $password;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Groups({"user:read", "user:write"})
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Groups({"user:read", "user:write"})
     */
    private $first_name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Groups({"user:read", "user:write"})
     */
    private $phone;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Groups({"user:read", "user:write"})
     */
    private $address;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Groups({"user:read", "user:write"})
     */
    private $city;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Groups({"user:read", "user:write"})
     */
    private $zip;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Groups({"user:read", "user:write"})
     */
    private $photo;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Groups({"user:read", "user:write"})
     */
    private $seeking_job_type;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Groups({"user:read", "user:write"})
     */
    private $seeking_job_contract;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Groups({"user:read", "user:write"})
     */
    private $availability;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     * @Groups({"user:read", "user:write"})
     */
    private $registration_date;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity=Cv::class, cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     * @Groups("user:read")
     */
    private $id_cv;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getEmail(): ?string
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function setEmail(string $email): self
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * A visual identifier that represents this user.
     *
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getUserIdentifier(): string
    {
        return (string) $this->email;
    }

    /**
     * @deprecated since Symfony 5.3, use getUserIdentifier instead
     */
    public function getUsername(): string
    {
        return (string) $this->email;
    }

    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getRoles(): array
    {
        $roles = $this->roles;
        // guarantee every user at least has ROLE_USER
        $roles[] = 'ROLE_USER';

        return array_unique($roles);
    }

    public function setRoles(array $roles): self
    {
        $this->roles = $roles;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @see PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface
     */
    public function getPassword(): string
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    public function setPassword(string $password): self
    {
        $this->password = $password;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Returning a salt is only needed, if you are not using a modern
     * hashing algorithm (e.g. bcrypt or sodium) in your security.yaml.
     *
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getSalt(): ?string
    {
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function eraseCredentials()
    {
        // If you store any temporary, sensitive data on the user, clear it here
        // $this->plainPassword = null;
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(string $name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getFirstName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->first_name;
    }

    public function setFirstName(string $first_name): self
    {
        $this->first_name = $first_name;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPhone(): ?string
    {
        return $this->phone;
    }

    public function setPhone(string $phone): self
    {
        $this->phone = $phone;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getAddress(): ?string
    {
        return $this->address;
    }

    public function setAddress(string $address): self
    {
        $this->address = $address;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCity(): ?string
    {
        return $this->city;
    }

    public function setCity(string $city): self
    {
        $this->city = $city;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getZip(): ?string
    {
        return $this->zip;
    }

    public function setZip(string $zip): self
    {
        $this->zip = $zip;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPhoto(): ?string
    {
        return $this->photo;
    }

    public function setPhoto(string $photo): self
    {
        $this->photo = $photo;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getSeekingJobType(): ?string
    {
        return $this->seeking_job_type;
    }

    public function setSeekingJobType(string $seeking_job_type): self
    {
        $this->seeking_job_type = $seeking_job_type;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getSeekingJobContract(): ?string
    {
        return $this->seeking_job_contract;
    }

    public function setSeekingJobContract(string $seeking_job_contract): self
    {
        $this->seeking_job_contract = $seeking_job_contract;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getAvailability(): ?string
    {
        return $this->availability;
    }

    public function setAvailability(string $availability): self
    {
        $this->availability = $availability;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getRegistrationDate(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->registration_date;
    }

    public function setRegistrationDate(\DateTimeInterface $registration_date): self
    {
        $this->registration_date = $registration_date;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getIdCv(): ?Cv
    {
        return $this->id_cv;
    }

    public function setIdCv(?Cv $id_cv): self
    {
        $this->id_cv = $id_cv;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

As you can see my properties : "first_name", "seeking_job_type" and "seeking_job_contract" are set as "@Groups({"user:read", "user:write"}) . Which I believe allow them to be writted.
But in API ressources they are "readOnly: true". So i can not manipulate them.
Do you know where I am wrong ? I'd like them to not be "readOnly".
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Solved.
I had to put underscore to my function ex : public function **setFirst_Name**(string $first_name): self